# What is *overflow in CSS?

Tags: css, sass, overflow, stylesheet

I clone a repository and see bellow CSS class

```
button,
input {
  *overflow: visible;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

I've never seen * prefix before overflow.what is *overflow exactly and what is the difference between overflow and *overflow?

Comment: it could be a typo or as I remember might be older version of IE browser hacks: http://mynthon.net/howto/-/webdev/CSS-big-list-of-css-hacks.txt, "Asterisk hack" for IE 5,6,7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be a typo or as I remember might be for browser compatible issues, for older version of IE browser [hacks](http://mynthon.net/howto/-/webdev/CSS-big-list-of-css-hacks.txt): "Asterisk hack" for IE 5,6,7.

This is used to be our life before the modern browser era, using hacks to fix browser compatible issues.